# Set Dart breakpoints in WebStorm

Tags: debugging, dart, breakpoints, webstorm

Dart code execution does not pause at breakpoints set in WebStorm IDE.

The browser config points at a local Dartium install (/home/tom/dart/chromium/chrome-wrapper).

The Chrome extension has been installed.

Clicking on "Debug index.html" in the IDE causes Dartium to be launched. "JetBrains IDE Support is debugging this tab" displays in Dartium.

Any hints as to where to look for a problem?

Edit: I think it's transpiling. Here's the log:

> [web] GET /begin/index.html => polymer_and_dart|web/begin/index.html
>   [web] GET /packages/web_components/dart_support.js =>
>   web_components|lib/dart_support.js [web] GET
>   /packages/web_components/webcomponents.js =>
>   web_components|lib/webcomponents.js
>   ...

Comment: What Dart and WebStorm version are you using?

Comment: You must not close the message about JetBrains IDE support?

Comment: Dart 1.10.1, Webstorm 10.0.4

Comment: Can step through Dart code in browser. No sign of transpiled Javascript, in case that means anything.

Comment: Dartium executes Dart directly without transpilation. There is no JS until you create it with `pub build` or load from `pub serve` using a browser that doesn't support Dart.

Comment: What about the release version of Chrome?

Comment: I would like to step through code in WebStorm rather than the browser tools.

Comment: Chrome loads JS only. I have no idea why it's not working for you. I just set a breakpoint, launch with debug and execution halts at the breakpoint.

Comment: Screenshot illustrating project structure may help to give an answer. I mean Project View with some expanded nodes. Where is index.html located. Where are dart files located in which you set breakpoints.

Comment: Here's the project: http://pasteboard.co/1VWg6CKA.png

Comment: Here's one w/ more structure: http://pasteboard.co/1W3IARD8.png

Comment: Screenshots look fine. What is your Dartium version (Help | About Chromium)? I just checked once again that WebStorm 10.0.4 + Dart SDK 1.10.1 + Dartium from Dart Editor 1.10.1 installation (version 39.0.2171.0) work fine with sample web application, breakpoints are hit.

Comment: Also please try the latest Dartium from https://www.dartlang.org/downloads/archive/

Comment: This is now working after much pain. I downloaded the latest dart-sdk and dartium. I put dart-sdk in ~/work/ and set my environment PATH to it. Then I downloaded the latest dartium, put it in ~/work/dartium, and added a PATH variable and alias to it in my shell startup script. The alias is .../dartium/chrome-wrapper --user-data-dir=~/.dartium/my_data_dir. (note that the Chromium website incorrectly lists "chromium" as the executable name). Then I went into the IDE settings "Languages and Frameworks" and set the SDK path to ~/work/dart-sdk. I left "Use custom profile directory" (?) unchecked.

Comment: I also unchecked the other browsers, particularly Chrome, in the Tools->Web Browsers dialog, and set "Custom path" to the chrome-wrapper executable (with no args).

Comment: Environment PATH doesn't matter for the IDE. You only have to set correct paths both to Dart SDK and to Dartium in Settings | Languages and Frameworks | Dart. You do not have to create wrapper scripts, or to disable/edit whatever in Tools | Web Browsers. Once path to Dartium is configured in Dart page, Dartium browser will appear in web Browsers page (after OK button). Though if you want you may check 'Use custom profile' for Dartium. Run configuration for index.html (Run | Edit Configurations...) by default is set up to be started in Dartium.

Comment: Setting paths to SDK and Dartium in Languages and Frameworks | Dart page doesn't look like much pain. Other actions are not necessary. Checking run configuration in Run | Edit Configurations is not a pain as well.

Comment: BTW, it's a beautiful IDE and debugger. I'm very happy to have it working.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 rather good articles on the topic:

https://medium.com/@kasperpeulen/debugging-dart-in-webstorm-c118c059cca3
https://medium.com/@kasperpeulen/debugging-dart-in-webstorm-part-2-673048da2a3f

While I might not know why exactly you cannot debug your application, reading through these might give you the answer what Kasper (author of the articles) does to make it work.

Comment: Humorous. But more of a general debugging tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Download fresh [Dartium](https://www.dartlang.org/downloads/archive/), set path to it in Settings (Preferences) | Languages and Frameworks | Dart. I'd recommend to update Dart SDK as well.
Check that run configuration for your html file is configured to start in Dartium (Run | Edit Configurations, for historical reasons its type is 'JavaScript Debug Run Configuration').